# How to print Package Variables

Tags: perl

How to Print all package variables in Perl.

I have 2 packages in same script, I want to get all the variables used in packageA in packageB

Comment: It would help to know what you want to achieve. A now-deleted comment mentioned [B::Xref](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Xref), which could very well do what you want, But I'm also concerned that you might be looking at the [wrong solution](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) to the problem you are facing. For example, maybe your goal is best served by `perlcritic`. Who knows, because you haven't told us what it is.

Comment: Please show a minimal example, see [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

What problem are you trying to solve?

But, there are so many other design issues here.

- If there's some central source of truth for values in your program, that package can provide an interface to request a value. This is what I tend to do.
- They are package variables, so package B can just use the variables from package A: `$A::some_var`.
- package A could export all of its variables to any other package that wants to use them. Several Perl modules, such as Socket and Fcntl, do this.
- If package B is really just a specialization of package A, inheritance might be the answer. You still need an interface though.